# Redirecting Apache2 public directory to directory: www inside /home/user in Ubuntu 21.04 for local development

Tags: permissions, apache2, directory, 21.04, document

I have changed the Apache2 public directory for years changing the content of file 
**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

so:

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/www
<Directory "/home/user/www">
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In the file: **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**
I wrote the follow line as last line

**ServerName localhost**

Then I go to restarted Apache with:

**sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart**

All the past times this have resulted but in Ubuntu 21.04 when I go In my Web Browser to: 
 **http://localhost** it show me 403 error:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

I see it have changed somthing in Apache. How can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Does the user under which Apache is running (may be 'apache', 'www-data' or similar) have access to your `/home/user/www` directory? Also look at the Apache error log, you may find more detailed explanation there.

Comment: Ok Thanks. It's a problem with the permissions

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the situation not moving the directory, only I have asigned permissions to my user to the directory **var/www/html**

```
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/html
sudo usermod -a -G www-data user
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html
sudo chmod -R g+s /var/www/html
sudo chown -R user /var/www/html
```